# Cannot link stylesheet from internet

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet at [static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css](http://static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css)

I used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css" type="text/css">
```

to link the stylesheet. However the page does not pick up the stylesheet and some divs are not working. Like this one only shows the words "construction" with no style although I put id and class.

```
<div id="construction" class="construction0"><font style="margin-left: 20px;">construction</font></div>
```

I must be doing something obviously wrong but I don't know what, it would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: try with http: // static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the http://, try this:

```
href="http://static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a full url, probably a [protocol relative url](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css" type="text/css">
```

Or, with the full protocol:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css" type="text/css">
```

You can test the url using an `<a href="static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css">link</a>` link. Clicking on this link leads to `http://yoursite.com/static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css` - [example](http://jsbin.com/EHiTEzAv)

For more information on relative URls, see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Specifically the [examples at 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4):

> Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
> `http://a/b/c/d;p?q`
> a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows.
>
> [...]
>
> - "g"             =  `"http://a/b/c/g"`
> - [...]
> - "//g"           =  `"http://g"`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css" type="text/css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use

> http://static.friedpanseller.com/magic.css
>   as href argument.

hope it help.